# GetComponent in Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, components

So i try to access the script component in another GameObject, but to do it faster i have a Component variable.

```
Component map = GameObject.FindWithTag("Map").GetComponent<Map>();
```

Now when i want to reference a variable inside a map component

```
map.selected = true;
```

it gives me an error that

> UnityEngine.Component does not contain a definition for selected".

Selected is a public bool in Map script, attached to the Map GameObject.

When i go with the long way

```
GameObject.FindWithTag("Map").GetComponent<Map>().selected = true;
```

everything works, but i'm looking for a way to shorten my code (this script uses variables from Map in many instances, so i want to write it the shorter way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you are instanciating your variable `map` as a Component, so the compiler will be looking for the selected attribute in the Component class.
Try something like this:
`MapScript map = GameObject.FindWithTag("Map").GetComponent<MapScript>();`
(Replace MapScript with the actual name of that script.)
I'm not entirely sure if this exact syntax will work, and I have no way of testing this at the moment, so please try and see if it works. If it doesn't, I will look into that as soon as I'm home.